# How to pass dynamic SQL result to DBCC commands as parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get database log name using dynamic SQL, and passing that result to `DBCC shrinkfile(@log, 5)`. But logs are not getting shrunk. I am getting query as result saying no logfile exist or it's moved.

Below code is printing the result:

```
use master
declare @test nvarchar(255)
declare @search nvarchar(10) = 'log'

SET @test = 'select Name
             from sys.database_files 
             where name like '''+'%' +@search+ '%' + ''''

EXECUTE sp_executesql @test

PRINT @test
```

But this code is throwing an error:

```
use master
declare @test nvarchar(255)
declare @search nvarchar(10) = 'log'

SET @test = 'select Name
             from sys.database_files 
             where name like '''+'%' +@search+ '%' + ''''

EXECUTE sp_executesql @test

DBCC SHRINKFILE(@test, 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a name to the output of the select.  Assuming there is one name that matches, then try this version:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(255);
declare @search nvarchar(10) = 'log';
declare @name sysname;

set @sql = '
select @name=Name
from sys.database_files
where name like ''%' +@search+ '%''
'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@name sysname output', @name=@name output;

select @name;
```

In your version, you are confusing the output of the `exec` with the `print`.  There is no result from the `print`.